# ¿Cómo personalizar botón de iniciar sesión de Google?

Tags: javascript

Mediante el siguiente código creamos un botón que nos permite hacer una autenticación con Google y funciona correctamente. Mi pregunta es como personalizarlo mediante CSS. He intentado usar el id `signInDiv` que es el correspondiente al contenedor pero no pareciera ser lo correcto:

```
useEffect(() => {
  google.accounts.id.initialize({
    client_id: '741783415419-47odd3rokk4c3hp8g9idk887vste71qp.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    callback: handleCallbackResponse
  })

  google.accounts.id.renderButton(
    document.getElementById('signInDiv'),
    { theme: 'outline', size: 'large' }
  )
}, [])
```